# How can I select the proper openai.api_version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-openai

I read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/chatgpt?pivots=programming-language-chat-completions:

```
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"
```

and on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193969/how-to-integrate-tiktoken-library-with-azure-opena:

```
openai.api_version = "2023-03-15-preview"
```

This makes me wonder: How can I select the proper `openai.api_version`? Does that depend on my Azure OpenAI instance or deployed models or which features I use in my Python code? Or something else?

I couldn't find the info in my deployed models:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API Version property depends on the method you are calling in the API: all methods are not supported in all API versions.

Details are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cognitive-services/openai/reference

And preview API lifecycle is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/api-version-deprecation => check those pages for up-to-date references

As of March 7th, 2024:
Example: "completions" endpoint is available in the following versions (ordered by date):

- 2024-02-15-preview
- 2023-12-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-09-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-08-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-07-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-06-01-preview (still supported, due to DALL-E 2)
- 2023-05-15
- 2023-03-15-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2022-12-01

But "chat completions" endpoint is available only in the following versions (ordered by date):

- 2024-02-15-preview
- 2023-12-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-09-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-08-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-07-01-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
- 2023-06-01-preview (still supported, due to DALL-E 2)
- 2023-05-15
- 2023-03-15-preview (retiring April 2, 2024)
  Because basically it was not offered in the initial API.

Generally, use the latest "not preview" version for production when possible, as the preview versions might be retired on a more frequent basis.

Answer (score 2):

`openai.api_version` is removed from `openai==1.0.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/migration?tabs=python-new%2Cdalle-fix#removed

You can still find it in `openai==0.28`

Comment: Thanks, I confirm, that broke my code recently.

Comment: To add a few details: it's not fully removed, it's replaced by the `api_version` parameter in the `AzureOpenAI` constructor - see differences in the samples in the link that you provided. So yes, if you have not set your `openai` package version in your project, you might have faced a breaking change (in November 2023)

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks, good point. To easily migrate from openai<1 to openai>=1: https://app.grit.io/migrations/new/openai (for other solutions: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742).